# Python Itertools Code Optimisation

Tags: python, optimization, python-itertools

> Given [question](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/w30/challenges/melodious-password) (the contest is ***now*** over)

- a password consists of exactly `n` lowercase English letters.
- the password is melodious, meaning that consonants can only be next to
  vowels and vowels can only be next to consonants. Example: `bawahaha`
- the password cannot contain the letter `y` (because it's both a
  consonant and vowel).
- the first letter of the password can be either
  a vowel or consonant.

[image]

#### Given the length, `n`, of the password,

print all of the possible passwords that meet the conditions above.

### Input Format

The line of input contains the integer  (the length of the password).

#### Constraints

### Output Format

Print each of the possible passwords, one per line. The order of the passwords does not matter.

My Code in Python:

```
import sys
import itertools

n = int(raw_input().strip())

consonants = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'z']
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']


test4 = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'z', 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
answer = set(itertools.product(test4, repeat=n))

for letters in answer:
    for j in xrange(len(letters)):
        flag = 1
        if j != len(letters) - 1:
            if letters[j] in vowels and letters[j+1] in vowels:
                flag = 0
                break
            if letters[j] in consonants and letters[j+1] in consonants:
                flag = 0
                break

    if flag:
        for j in letters:
            sys.stdout.write(j)
        print ""
```

### Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Questions about improving already-working code belong on [codereview.se], not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there's a better way (if you mean faster). You can generate a `itertools.product` where you don't have to "discard" items.

You can simply create a `product` of `vowel, consonant, vowel, consonant, ...` (alternating both lists `n` times) and one which starts with `consonant, vowel, consonant, vowel, ...`. The returned items will always satisfy the condition so all that needs to be done is `print`ing them.

```
import itertools

def alternating(seq1, seq2, length):
    """Generator that alternatingly yields seq1 and seq2, `length` times"""
    assert length >= 0
    for _ in range(length // 2):
        yield seq1
        yield seq2
    if length % 2 == 1:
        yield seq1

consonants = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'z']
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

n = int(raw_input().strip())

# Starts with vowel
for comb in itertools.product(*list(alternating(vowels, consonants, n))):
    print(''.join(comb))

# Starts with consonant
for comb in itertools.product(*list(alternating(consonants, vowels, n))):
    print(''.join(comb))
```

That way you can reduce the number of possible candidates.

Your approach gave `25**n` items, while the new approach only generates `2 * 5**(n//2)*20**(n//2)` (if `n` even) or `5**(n//2 + 1) * 20 ** (n//2) + 5**(n//2) * 20 ** (n//2 + 1)` (if `n` odd) items.

For `n=5` that means: What generated originally `9765625` items (almost 10 million!) from `product` will now only generate `250000` items. Even ignoring the (possibly very expensive) check if your sequence satisfies the problem-condition (which is obsolete now) you generated 40 times more items in your `product`!